# BigDecimal gives NumberFormatException in Android 4.0.3 with localization

Tags: android, localization, bigdecimal, decimalformat

I am doing localization in my app with Persian(locale-"fa") and Pashto(locale-"ps") languages.. When i am trying to convert double value in BigDecimal using Decimal Foramt then it gives NumberFormatException  in 4.0.3 with Persian language.

Following is my code to get two decimal places:

```
public static String roundTwoDecimals(double d) {

    System.out.println("===================Amount in double "+d);
    DecimalFormat twoDForm = new DecimalFormat("#############.##");
    String format=twoDForm.format(d);
    System.out.println("===================Amount after formatting "+format);
    return new BigDecimal(twoDForm.format(d)).toPlainString();
}
```

**LogCat:**

```
03-26 15:19:29.714: I/System.out(1475): ===================Amount in double 166308.37
03-26 15:19:29.723: I/System.out(1475): ===================Amount after formatting ۱۶۶۳۰۸٫۳۷
```

Actual amount is 166308.37 and when i change language to **persian("fa")** and format it, it gives amount like `۱۶۶۳۰۸٫۳۷` in 4.0.3 .
So this string can not be converted to `BigDecimal` and gives `NumberFormatException`.

And strange problem is that except 4.0.3, it works perfectly fine.

Comment: When you change localization, the decimal seperator `.` changes to `,` in some languages. You need to take care this thing.

Comment: Ya thats fine... but how to take care of this thing. i have already tried with replace function to replace . to , but still its not replacing.

Comment: On which device you are testing it ?

Comment: Micromax Canvas A110. Os 4.0.3

Comment: Yes you are right, I ran your code in 4.0.3 and 4.2 but in 4.0.3 it gave me this error too.

Comment: Do some needful in this...any suggestions?

Comment: @NiravBhandari, Is this your question or Kinjal's question ?

Comment: we both are trying...

Comment: @Kedarnath Yes , we both are trying..

Comment: Now we three are trying :)

Comment: give us some solution kedarnath...yu are belonging from mahadev's family..you must have some solution to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code..

```
public static String roundTwoDecimals(double d) {

    NumberFormat nf=NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
    DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat)nf;
    df.applyPattern("#############.##");
    String output = df.format(d);

    return new BigDecimal(output).toPlainString();
}
```

Comment: Good , that you found solution your self, Nirav :)